# Access sub array in html angular

Tags: angular, primeng, angular9, angular10

I am working on angular app. I am using primeng carousel in my app. My code is as follows:

```
<p-carousel
  [value]="products"
  [numVisible]="3"
  [numScroll]="3"
  [circular]="false"
  [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <h5>Basic</h5>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-product let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
    <div class="product-item">
      <div class="product-item-content">
        <div class="p-mb-3"></div>
        <div>
          <p>{{ product.id }}</p>
          <h4 class="p-mb-1">{{ product.name }}</h4>
          <h6 class="p-mt-0 p-mb-3">${{ product.price }}</h6>
          <span
            [class]="
              'product-badge status-' + product.inventoryStatus.toLowerCase()
            "
            >{{ product.inventoryStatus }}</span
          >
          <div class="car-buttons p-mt-5">
            <p-button
              type="button"
              styleClass="p-button p-button-rounded p-mr-2"
              icon="pi pi-search"
            ></p-button>
            <p-button
              type="button"
              styleClass="p-button-success p-button-rounded p-mr-2"
              icon="pi pi-star"
            ></p-button>
            <p-button
              type="button"
              styleClass="p-button-help p-button-rounded"
              icon="pi pi-cog"
            ></p-button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        *ngFor="let cityData of myData; let i = index"
        style="position: relative;margin-top: 2rem;border-bottom: 1px solid #4E5668;"
      >
        <div style="display: flex; margin:1em; ">
          <span style="flex:1;">{{ cityData.name }}</span>
          <span style="flex:1;">
            <p-checkbox
              name="product"
              [value]="cityData.id"
              (onChange)="toggleVisibility($event, cityData, product)"
              #checkbox
            ></p-checkbox>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-carousel>
```

Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-carousel-demo-fjw4ap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

In this carousel I have some checkboxes as shown in stackblitz. My array is as follows -

```
myData = [
    {
      myid: 1,
      name: 'paris',
      status: [
        {
          id: 1000,
          active: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 1001,
          active: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      myid: 2,
      name: 'London',
      status: [
        {
          id: 1003,
          active: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 1004,
          active: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

So I want to set checkbox as checked when id from product array matches id in status array of myData array. So, in html at runtime I want to write a code when myData is looping, I need to access status array of myData and match id. if product.id and myData.status[i].id are equal, then I need to check active field. If active is 1 then set checkbox as true, if active is 0 then se checkbox as false.

How can I have this code in html to access status array in above html code , pass id and access value of active variable?

Comment: Are you using your `status` array only for setting checkbox value?  Can the user interact with the checkbox value?

Comment: yes this status array is coming from api. I need to match product id with id in status array and set checkbox value using active attribute of status array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to avoid complex operations in HTML templates. They are not
> performant & a bad practice.

Also, calling a method (that could return true/false if product id is in `status` array) from HTML is also not recommended.

The best way to do it is to transform `status` array into an `Object` of type `[productId: string]:number`

```
{
      myid: 1,
      name: 'paris',
      status: {
          "1000":1,
          "1001":1,   
       }
},
```

This makes it easier to access a product Id `myData.status.id`.

**Approach 1:** If you have control over the Backend, you should transform the `status` into an object from there.

**Approach 2:** You can't control Backend: Transform the `status` array into an object when you get it in the response. Use Rxjs pipe & map the response:

```
 getData().pipe(map(response=>{
  //Assuming response is the data currently in this.myData
  response.forEach(city=>{
    const mappedStatus=city.status.reduce((acc,current)=>{
      acc[current.id]=current.active;
      return acc;
    },{});

    city.status={...mappedStatus};
  });
  return response;
}))
```

In HTML where you place your checkbox: (A simple checkbox. Add other handlers that you require)

```
 <p-checkbox
    binary="true"
    trueValue="1"
    falseValue="0"
    [ngModel]="cityData.status[product.id]"
  ></p-checkbox>
```

Comment: Doubt in approach 2: Sorry I am new in angular. Once your approach 2 return response, how I can access it in html?

Comment: is it possible to update in stackblitz?

Comment: @Nandini updated. https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-carousel-demo-wwfs9w?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I am using primeng 9. I am getting Can't bind to 'trueValue' since it isn't a known property of 'p-checkbox'. Any other way to do this?

Comment: @Nandini Please go through the documentation for primeng v9

Comment: Since the scope of this question was accessing array in HTML, you can open a new question regarding data binding in primeng v9 checkbox

Comment: ok I will open and paste link here. You can answer

Comment: Asked this question here stackoverflow.com/questions/70880288/truevalue-anf-falsevalue-not-working-in-checkbox Please provide answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880288/truevalue-anf-falsevalue-not-working-in-checkbox

Comment: I understood documentation but finding it difficult to implement it in your solution. Could you please help?

Comment: @Nandini Sure, Will help in that question. But if this solution answers your initial problem with array, please mark it as an answer to help others too.

Comment: accepted...request you to please help in that question as your solution seems good to me