# trueValue anf falseValue not working in checkbox

Tags: angular, primeng, angular9

I am working on angular app and using treetable of primeng.I am using primng v9. my code is as follows:

```
<p-carousel
  [value]="products"
  [numVisible]="3"
  [numScroll]="3"
  [circular]="false"
  [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <h5>Basic</h5>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-product let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
    <div class="product-item">
      <div class="product-item-content">
        <div class="p-mb-3"></div>
        <div>
          <p>{{ product.id }}</p>
          <h4 class="p-mb-1">{{ product.name }}</h4>
          <h6 class="p-mt-0 p-mb-3">${{ product.price }}</h6>
          <span
            [class]="
              'product-badge status-' + product.inventoryStatus.toLowerCase()
            "
            >{{ product.inventoryStatus }}</span
          >
          <div class="car-buttons p-mt-5">
            <p-button
              type="button"
              styleClass="p-button p-button-rounded p-mr-2"
              icon="pi pi-search"
            ></p-button>
            <p-button
              type="button"
              styleClass="p-button-success p-button-rounded p-mr-2"
              icon="pi pi-star"
            ></p-button>
            <p-button
              type="button"
              styleClass="p-button-help p-button-rounded"
              icon="pi pi-cog"
            ></p-button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        *ngFor="let cityData of myData; let i = index"
        style="position: relative;margin-top: 2rem;border-bottom: 1px solid #4E5668;"
      >
        <div style="display: flex; margin:1em; ">
          <span style="flex:1;">{{ cityData.name }}</span>
          <span style="flex:1;">
            <p-checkbox
              name="product"
              binary="true"
              [trueValue]="1"
              [falseValue]="0"
              [ngModel]="cityData.status[product.id]"
              (onChange)="toggleVisibility($event, cityData, product)"
              #checkbox
            ></p-checkbox>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-carousel>
```

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-carousel-demo-wwfs9w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I am getting following error:

```
Can't bind to 'trueValue' since it isn't a known property of 'p-checkbox'.
```

same for falseValue. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What is your angular version?

Comment: angular 9 and primeng 9. I used latest stackblitz here which I got online but please provide solution as per version 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeng v9 doesn't have `trueValue` and `falseValue`.

In v9, you need to bind a boolean to `p-checkbox` like this:

```
<p-checkbox
 name="product"
 binary="true"
 [ngModel]="cityData.status[product.id]===1"
 (onChange)="toggleVisibility($event, cityData, product)"
 #checkbox
 ></p-checkbox>
```

Here, you are adding a 1-way binding to the p-checkbox. This binds a boolean value with checkbox:`cityData.status[product.id]===<your-expected-value>`

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used PrimeNG, but based on their docs and examples:

Assuming it is 9.2.8-lts, per their docs https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v9-lts/#/checkbox `p-checkbox` does not have any such property. Instead you would track the selected state by using the `[(ngModel)]`

So what you would need to do is set your loop to be like:

```
<div
        *ngFor="let cityData of myData; let i = index"
        style="position: relative;margin-top: 2rem;border-bottom: 1px solid #4E5668;"
      >
        <div style="display: flex; margin:1em; ">
          <span style="flex:1;">{{ cityData.name }}</span>
          <span style="flex:1;">
            <p-checkbox
              name="product"
              binary="true"
              value="city" 
              [value]="city"
              [(ngModel)]="selectedCities"
              (onChange)="toggleVisibility($event, cityData, product)"
              #checkbox
            ></p-checkbox>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then in your component file you would define a `selectedCities` array which will be of the same type as what your overall `myData` array is.

Refer to their stackblitz that is attached in their docs.

Edit: Looks like `trueValue` and `falseValue` were added in version 12. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v12-lts/#/checkbox

Comment: I understood their code but I am facing onChange in my stackblitz

Comment: Your linked stackblitz doesn't have an onChange. And the package.json file has primeng of version 13.0.4:     "primeng": "13.0.4",

Comment: yes in stackblitz it is 13. But please consider version 9 and provide solution

Comment: Mate, I told you that v9 does not have a trueValue or falseValue, if you want to use trueValue and falseValue then upgrade to version 12 or higher. Otherwise use two way binding on your ngModel to track which cities are selected or not as is shown in their stackblitz for version 9 of checkbox.

Comment: I compulsoroly don't want to use trueValue and falseValue. I just want that for version 9, I code should work. If you see my code and ngModel. and in component it is bit complicated. I am finding it hard to convert it to v9 code

Comment: Well if you don't want to use trueValue and falseValue then just remove them, but you would still need to make your code work with v9 as its version of the checkbox probably has subtle implementation differences compared to v13 which has its own.  GO to their website, select v9 from the right side (where it has the version, by default it is 13) and look at the components you need and how their stackblitz examples have it implemented as a guide

Comment: my code is bit different from the examples mentioned on their website have a look at my checkbox code and ngOninit.